# I get a NullExceptionPointer on my onClickListener on my RecyclerView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

It keeps on popping. I've checked my syntax already. Help!
My code goes like this, they click the edit button, an dialog pops up, then updates my SQLite database.

**Here's my viewHolder**

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView foodTextView;
    TextView calorieTextView;
    Button editButton;
    Button deleteButton;

    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        foodTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.food_text_view);
        calorieTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.calorie_text_view);
        editButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
        deleteButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        editButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.edit_button){
            itemClickCallback.onEditClick(this.getAdapterPosition());
        } else if(view.getId()==R.id.delete_button){
            itemClickCallback.onDeleteClick(this.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the implementation of the interface**

```
public void onEditClick(int p) {
    foodDatabaseAdapter.helper.getWritableDatabase();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    EditItemDialog editItemDialog = new EditItemDialog();
    editItemDialog.show(manager,"EditItemDialog");
}
```

I've tried other stuff like `getLayoutPosition()` but it does the same thing. I've edited it some more though I can't remember the changes I made but it seems to be working for one time only everytime I run the app but crashes the next time I try to edit. It also doesn't update after the first edit. Help!

**Here's the error log**

```
06-22 10:27:18.624 25685-25685/com.leviebora.simplecaloriecounter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.leviebora.simplecaloriecounter, PID: 25685
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.leviebora.simplecaloriecounter.MyAdapter$ItemClickCallback.onEditClick(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.leviebora.simplecaloriecounter.MyAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(MyAdapter.java:54)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

ItemClickCallback is in the adapter class. Here is the code to set it.

```
private ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback;

public interface ItemClickCallback {
    void onEditClick(int p);
    void onDeleteClick(int p);
}

public void setItemClickCallback(final ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback){
    this.itemClickCallback = itemClickCallback;
}
```

**Here is the onCreate**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    Date todayDate = new Date();
    thisDate = currentDate.format(todayDate);

    foodDatabaseAdapter = new FoodDatabaseAdapter(this);

    /* prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("runToday", MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit = prefs.edit();
    itemNumber = prefs.getInt("runToday",0);*/

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(this,getData());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setItemClickCallback(this);

}
```

Edited my adapter constructor. Here's the fix.

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data, ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback ) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.itemClickCallback = itemClickCallback;
    this.data = data;

}
```

Comment: Where does `itemClickCallback` come from?

Comment: your _itemClickCallback_ is null. Also whenever you make a listener just check if it is null or not before use it.

Comment: So at where you'r registering _setItemClickCallback()_ method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check  "itemClickCallback" interface not initialized properly.. may be

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback;

        public interface ItemClickCallback {
            void onEditClick(int p);
            void onDeleteClick(int p);
        }


         public ViewHolder(View v, ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback) {
                super(v);
                ...........................
            .............................
             this.itemClickCallback = itemClickCallback;
            } 

}
```

Comment: How do I initialize it?

Comment: My asuumption was correct..plz check... I think you got it , yet I share my full answer..

Answer (score 0):

On you adaptor write the function

```
 public void setTtemClickCallback(itemClickCallback item) {
   this.itemClickCallback = item;
 }
```

and give in the fragment

```
adaptor.setTtemClickCallback(this);
```

Hope this may help

Comment: It is already in my adapter and my activity.

Comment: are you sure you are registering the interface, like this `adaptorobject.setTtemClickCallback(this);` @wonderland0422

Comment: try passing `Activity.this` to the MyAdaptor  @wonderland0422

Comment: adapter = new MyAdapter(Activity.this,getData());

something like that? It shows a red underline.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your callback to the view holder. For instance, by the constructor:

```
private ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback;

public ViewHolder(View v, ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback) {
    super(v);
    this.itemClickCallback = itemClickCallback;
    //more code
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: Show the code where you initialize the view holder.

Comment: I already fixed it. I'll add in the edit. Thanks!